# Solving timeseries regression problem with LSTM and TF

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, lstm

I have a huge dataset from Mooc Course, which contains student's logs (log sequence) during the course.
I want to predict user outcomes from (a part of) raw user's log data with deep learning (LSTM+Timeseries).
For example: *user11* has 1000 log rows in the course, and I will use 10% of its log data (first 100 log rows) to predict its final grade.

My theory is the next: the data contains all user's habits (path), success points (sum of success point is the final grade) to predict user final outcomes. For example, 100% amount of user log contains all SUCCESS points(and users paths during the course), which tells us the FINAL GRADE for each USER.

The question is: what is the minimum amount(%) of log data to predict user outcome? Can we predict the Final Outcome from 10% or 20% or 30% of data?

To make this, I use this dataset, which contains categorical and numeric values both.

[image]

As a first step I have used LabelEncoder for **event, link** and **resource** columns. Each user has its history, which means every user has a different length of log-history. (user11 -> 1000 rows, user22->1542 rows, etc.) To handle this I have created a generator which uses PADDING.

I give this padded data to the next Neural network:

[image]

If I use short sequences (like 50 or 80) it works well, but the MAE is very HIGH.
If I want to use long sequences (like 150 or 300) I always got NAN for loss.

Do you have any idea to decrease MAE and increase the length of the sequence without getting NAN fo loss?

The network is:

```
dropout=0.2
n_timesteps = 100
opt=Adam(learning_rate=0.01)   

# embedding head Event
inputs1 = Input(shape=(n_timesteps,))
embed_layer1 = Embedding(num_of_event, 30, input_length=n_timesteps,mask_zero=True)(inputs1)

# embedding head Link
inputs2 = Input(shape=(n_timesteps,))
embed_layer2 = Embedding(num_of_link, 30, input_length=n_timesteps, mask_zero=True)(inputs2)

# embedding head resource_display_name
inputs3 = Input(shape=(n_timesteps,))
embed_layer3 = Embedding(num_of_resource, 30, input_length=n_timesteps, mask_zero=True)(inputs3)

# lstm head Success
inputs4 = Input(shape=(n_timesteps,1))
lstm_layer = GRU(100, activation='relu', dropout=dropout, return_sequences=True)(inputs4)

# merged head
merged = concatenate([embed_layer1,embed_layer2,embed_layer3,lstm_layer])
merged = GRU(100, activation='relu', dropout=dropout,return_sequences=True,recurrent_dropout=dropout)(merged)
merged = GRU(100, activation='relu',dropout=dropout)(merged)
dense1 = Flatten()(merged)
dense1 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(dense1)
dense1 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(dense1)    
outputs =Dense(1)(dense1)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2, inputs3, inputs4], outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=opt)
```

Comment: A couple things I noticed.  Your learning rate is very high.  Try the default for Adam and train slowly.   What is your batch size?   Play with that.  A lower batch size will train faster with more variance, and vice versa.  'mae' may not be the greatest loss function for what you are trying to do.  You could consider 'mse', or fully trying to predict a distribution (see tensorflow_probability) and using a logloss.  Also, I'm not sure you need that FC network at the end with a model this complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try ADAM default LR. While I use GENERATOR with model.fit_generator(.....) as i know the batch size is 1. I could delete FC network, and I will connect the last GRU to Dense(1). Does it make sense?

Comment: I don't think the FCN will hurt, just adds complexity.  You can certainly try with and without.  fit_generator is deprecated in TF 2.3.1, so you can just use fit.  Best practice in the new TF is to use tf.data.  Either way, I would try a more careful training first and see how that goes.

Comment: Could you describe this: "or fully trying to predict a distribution (see tensorflow_probability) and using a logloss"  LogLoss is not using for Multiclass problem?